# use different array lists as a dropdown list on streamlit app

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, streamlit

I am developing a streamlit dashboard and I have  different array lists that look like this

```py
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st

svm_pred = np.array([1.50, 2.51, 3.34, 4.123, 5.22])
linear_pred = np.array([0.31, 2.11, 0.33, 4.0, 5])
bayesian_pred = np.array([1, 2.56, 3.89, 4, 5])
```

Now, I am using this arrays to plot different graphs and due to that I want the arrays to be selected from a dropdown list where when selected, it will automatically plot the graph.

Here is how I created my dropdown list:

```py
preds = {
    'SVM Predictions': svm_pred,
    'Polynomial Regression Predictions': linear_pred,
    'Bayesian Ridge Regression Predictions': bayesian_pred,
}

model_predict = st.sidebar.selectbox(
        "Select the model to predict : ", list(preds.keys()))
```

On plotting code, I call the model_predict selectbox to plot the chart,otherwise the chart will be empty.

```py
plot_predictions(adjusted_dates, world_cases, model_predict, 
    'SVM Predictions', 'purple')
plot_predictions(adjusted_dates, world_cases, model_predict,
    'Polynomial Regression Predictions', 'orange')
plot_predictions(adjusted_dates, world_cases, model_predict,
    'Bayesian Ridge Regression Predictions', 'green')
```

When I run the code, I get this error

> ValueError: Illegal format string "Polynomial Regression Predictions"; two marker symbols

What am I missing and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution from streamlit community.

Here is the link: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-selectbox-use-array-list/35126/2?u=livingstone90